# Different images for different place types in Google Maps with Google Places library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places

I'm brand new to javascript and can't figure out the logic to use different custom icons for the results of different types of places using the places library in google maps.
For example - this will request stadiums and parks

```
var request = {
      location: myLatLng,
      radius: 20000,
      types: ['stadium','park']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
```

A callback function includes a create marker function

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]); 
      } 
    }
}
```

the create marker function looks like this

```
var emu = 'EMU_test_icon.png'

function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: emu,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
```

So I know how to assign all markers to use the EMU_test_icon image, but how can I direct the results of the "stadium" place type to the icon I have listed (emu) but create the marker for results of "park" to a different custom icon (image2)?

Answer (score 0):

The "place" parameter which is passed into the createMarker method has a "type" property that can help.  See the reference [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses) under the PlaceSearchResults heading.

You can store the two icons in a map and lookup the type of icon based on the type of place.

```
// store the icons in a map, key'd by type
var iconMap = {'stadium': 'EMU_test_stadium_icon.png', 'park': 'EMU_test_park_icon.png'};

// access types array from PlaceResult object
//  search to find the string "stadium" and "park"
//  default the type to stadium and check to see if place is a park
//  if its a park update the type of icon we select
//  in the original call to create a marker, get the icon string by type
function createMarker(place) {

    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location,
        isStadium = place.types.indexOf("stadium") !== -1,
        isPark = place.types.indexOf("park") !== -1,
        iconType = "stadium";

    if (isPark) {
        iconType = "park";
    }

    new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: iconMap[iconType],
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

}
```

*Note: this will not work in IE < 9 (without adding indexOf function to the array prototype)

*Note2: assuming your "map" var is declared elsewhere